# Extracting a specific subarray in Julia

Tags: julia

from the array

```
[3,1,7,2;
4,3,2,7;
3,4,1,2]
```

I would like to extract the subarray corresponding to the rows having last entree equal to 2.

I am a Matlab user trying to start using Julia. I looked up for an hint in the docs but failed to find a working answer.

Thank you very much in advance,

Stephane

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
julia> x = [3 1 7 2
            4 3 2 7
            3 4 1 2]
3x4 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  1  7  2
 4  3  2  7
 3  4  1  2

julia> x[x[:, end] .== 2, :]
2x4 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  1  7  2
 3  4  1  2
```

Let's break it down.

`x[:, end]` is the last column.

`x[:, end] .== 2` gives is a `Vector{Bool}` (1d array of `true` and `false`), where we have `true` if that row ends in a 2 and `false` otherwise.

Then putting it all together we have `x[x[:, end] .== 2, :]`, which takes this vector of `true` and `false` to specify which rows and the `,:` says take all columns in each of those rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot spencerlyon2 !